# Adding ContaineRequestFilter to Undertow deployment

Tags: java, jax-rs, undertow

Do I need to configure Undertow to allow ContainerRequestFilter?

My filter looks like this, but it does not seem to be getting called.

```
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you registering your resource classes? Register the filter the same way.

Comment: I am registering them as shown in [Undertow documentation] (http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/#creating-a-servlet-deployment).

    addFilter(new FilterInfo(name, class))

But ContainerRequestServlet is not a Filter. Is there another way to register these kind of filters?

Comment: How are you registering your resource classes?

Comment: If you have the [`resteasy-undertow`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-undertow) dependency, it's much easier to configure your application. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Embedded_Container.html#d4e1428)

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet for the help. I added my filter as a resource to my undertow Application and that seems to fix it.